# TeamCity publish build Info

Tags: gradle, artifactory, teamcity-7.0

TeamCity has a feature which will publish the Build Information to artifactory always.(by default). If we check that publish build info option(in step 3  - i'm using gradle as Runner), The published information will be recorded in Artifactory so that, we can trace back to the build which produced the artifact. 
   Now i want to disable publishing build information if the build is person build. How to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't possible without customizing either the [TeamCity Artifactory plugin](https://github.com/JFrogDev/teamcity-artifactory-plugin) or the [Gradle Artifactory plugin](https://github.com/JFrogDev/build-info/tree/master/build-info-extractor-gradle).

Build Info descriptor deployment is currently decided upon using a boolean variable, but customizing either plugin to do what you need should be fairly easy.

Comment: HI.. is there any way to extend the artifactory plugin class and do our required changes?(with out touching the plugin, bcoz new version plugin may override the existing one)

Comment: Unfortunately no. You could always fork the project, apply your changes and open a pull request to have them included in the upstream.